# Swift Firebase Doesn't invoke method of observeSingleEvent

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve data of logged in user from Firebase. However, it doesn't go inside of the method of observeSigleEvent and populate the data, so that, when it comes to the cellForRowAtIndexpath method, posts array returns as nil and gives error of fatal error: Index out of range.

Code is below.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var homeActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser


var loggedInUserData : AnyObject?

var posts = [AnyObject?]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // get loggedinUser Details

    self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid ).observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: {
        (snapshot) in

        if(snapshot.exists()){
            self.loggedInUserData = snapshot

            // get all posts that are made by user
            self.databaseRef.child("posts/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (snapshot2) in
                if(snapshot2.exists()){
                    self.posts.append(snapshot2)
                    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath (row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
                    self.homeActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                }else{return}
            }){(error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }else{return}
    })
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : homeViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeViewTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! homeViewTableViewCell

    let post = posts[(self.posts.count-1) - (indexPath ).row]!.value(forKey: "text") as! String

    cell.configure(profilePic: nil, name: self.loggedInUserData!.value(forKey: "name") as! String, handle: self.loggedInUserData!.value(forKey: "handle") as! String, post: post)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because all the tableView functions are called when the ViewController is first initialised, while the data from Firebase won't come in for a (relatively) long time after initialisation. When

```
let post = posts[(self.posts.count-1) - (indexPath ).row]!.value(forKey: "text") as! String
```

Is called, it is trying to access index -1 of an array with nothing in it, hence your exception.

To fix your problem try setting the following to dynamically change the number of rows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.posts.count
}
```

Each time your child added listener is called, update the tableView with `tableView.reloadData()`.